# What does "G D C +" or "G C D +" stand for on LED strip controllers?

Tags: led-strip

*I'm not very well-versed in electrical engineering, so I'd be glad to get some beginner-friendly answers.*

I have a device similar to this ([source](https://www.uskyled.com/shop/ws2811-ws2812b-led-pixel-strip-light-controller-usb-dc-3keys-rf-14-17-21keys-with-remote-controller-dc5-24v/)), used for controlling LED strips (through PWM I think):

[image: LED strip controller]

The one in the picture has **"G D C +"** printed on the side towards the LED strip, mine has **"G C D +"** on it. Weirdly, I can't figure out what the letters stand for - I suppose it's some sort of abbreviations for which connector has what function (e.g. G = "ground"), but what are those? And why are there 4 characters if there are only 3 cables?

Comment: Your specific device has only 3 wires and so is probably wired for a 3-wire LED strip like ws2812, but 4 wire (SPI, etc) strips also exist which will have data and clock.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- + (red) is V+
- C (green) is data and clock for [WS2811](http://www.world-semi.com/DownLoadFile/106), WS2812 etc. protocol
- G (white in this case, sometimes
  red+black, sometimes blue) is ground

Some LED strips have separate data and clock wires- they use the more standard (in industry) SPI protocol which allows 10x faster data transfer than the 800kHz WS2812 etc. single-wire protocol.

Typical wiring from [here](https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/SP002E-Mini-RGB-LED-Controller-Dimmer_60840652780.html?spm=a2700.details.0.0.42d52809Edu6lz):

[image]

Comment: So on the controller, there are likely 4 connectors, but only 3 are wired in this case (for the WS8211+ protocol), right?

Comment: Yes, four pads on the PCB or whatever but three wires coming off them.

Comment: Presumably D is data and C is clock.

Comment: Presumably this circuit can control both the clock-less and clock-ful types of LED strips and this one is set for the clock-less type and has no clock wire attached.

Answer (score 7):

I would assume that G D C + stands for Ground / Data / Clock / +V.

bigclive did a nice tear down on this if you are interested https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jOo5lf4tVT4